# XPages - repeat control - show less rows via xe:pagerAddRows possible?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have for a repeat control a xe:pagerAddRows control to show more rows. I would like to display something similar to show / shrink the number of rows. I tried to set the rowCount propoerty to a negative value but this does not seem to work.

How can I achieve such a show less rows function?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use xe:pagerAddRows to reduce the number of rows - like the name anticipates.

Here is a way to create two buttons to show more or to show less rows:

```xml
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    viewScope.numberrows = 5
}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>

<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="#{javascript: parseInt(viewScope.numberrows)}"  ... >
    ...
</xp:repeat>

<xp:button value="show more" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="repeat1">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.numberrows += 5}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:button value="show less" id="button2">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="repeat1">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.numberrows -= 5}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

You can change the property "rows" (= number of rows to show) dynamically this way. This property is available in repeat controls, view controls and other multi row controls.

Comment: I fear you will miss some features like getRowCount or getRows which works normally with the pagerAddRows control. and you have to define a minimum number of rows cause a negative number in the viewscope does not work for the repeater.

Comment: You have viewScope.numberrows instead to get the values for getRowCount and getRows. Yes, you should make sure the calculation of row numbers should not be smaller than 5 or so. You can use link controls instead of button controls if you need to look it more pagerAddRows-ish. And, what would be the alternative?

Comment: The advantage with the Extension Library is that if you want to know how it works, the source code is available, in this case https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/blob/a1746104af1c6dc1b430206678860109dc407832/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls/src/com/ibm/xsp/extlib/component/data/UIPagerAddRows.java#L163. So you won't miss anything by building the functionality. `getRowCount()` isn't changed by Pager Add Rows. `getRows()` maps to your viewScope variable, so I don't see why it wouldn't get what you expect.

Comment: You could also use this approach https://www.intec.co.uk/a-cool-use-for-components-binding-property/ to bind the `xp:repeat` to a variable name, so you can get a handle on it from your button and call `setRows()` with the same code as the UIPagerAddRows.